# Font-Face changing via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, font-face

So the basic workflow is this:

1. Asynchronous file upload of a font (this is already done).
2. Get the URL (done).
3. Change the font to the new URL.

I realize this needs to be done via font-face, but I can't seem to figure out how to access that via JavaScript.

Comment: https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can create a new `<style>` element with the `@font-face` rule and append it to the `document`'s `head`:

```
var newStyle = document.createElement('style');
newStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\
@font-face {\
    font-family: " + yourFontName + ";\
    src: url('" + yourFontURL + "') format('yourFontFormat');\
}\
"));

document.head.appendChild(newStyle);
```

Of course, you'll probably need to provide all the necessary font formats and URLs, too, unless you're only worried about support for modern desktop browsers (in which case you would just use WOFF – I assume that's reasonable, because of the other features you mentioned).

Comment: Now, I understand. I was thinking he mean the html tag <font> with the face attribute and that he wanted to write it in Javascript. +1

Answer (score 20):

**Define a FontFace object**:

```
new_font = new FontFace('conthrax', 'url(fonts/conthrax-sb.ttf)')
```

**Call its load method to download the font**:

```
new_font.load().then(function(loaded_face) {
    // use font here

}).catch(function(error) {

});
```

... this returns a Promise, which when resolved passes the loaded FontFace.

**Add the loaded font to the document**:

```
new_font.load().then(function(loaded_face) {
    // use font here
    document.fonts.add(loaded_face)
}).catch(function(error) {

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
let font = new FontFace("ExampleFont", 'url(ExampleFont.woff2) format("woff2")');
font.load().then(function(loadedFont)
{
    document.fonts.add(loadedFont);
    //do something after the font is loaded
}).catch(function(error) {
    // error occurred
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using js to create style element in document and then append TextNode child to it.
Simple function:

```
function loadFont(name,url){
    var newStyle = document.createElement('style');
    newStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode('@font-face{font-family: '+name+'; src: url('+url+');}'));
    document.body.appendChild(newStyle)
}
```

Example using:

```
loadFont("bonbon","fonts/bonbon.ttf");
```