# how change the font with javascript having the font installed on the local machine?

Tags: javascript

I have a specific font on my local machine. When I create an element and apply inside method `textContent` the following JavaScript code doesn't change the font family.

custom.js:

```
// create a element head
var headElement = document.createElement('style');
headElement.textContent = "@font-face {\
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P';\
  font-style: normal;\
  font-weight: 400;\
  src: local('Press Start 2P'),\
  url(../fonts/Press_start_2P/PressStart2P-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');\
}";
document.head.appendChild( headElement );

// create tag a
var newElement = document.createElement("a");
newElement.textContent = "Link 1";

newElement.style.fontFamily = 'Press Start 2P';

var element = document.getElementById("list");
element.children[0].appendChild(newElement);
```

index.php:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

I hope that somebody helps me and I apologize for my English. I'm trying write better!

Comment: Your English is really good, keep up :) Btw, I wish I could help you with this, currently I know only how to use fonts from the GoogleFonts service :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font-Face changing via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355147/font-face-changing-via-javascript)

Comment: This is not how to create CSS Stylesheets dynamically. You need to use the **[CSS Object Model (CSSOM)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model)** to dynamically create a new stylesheet.

Comment: If it is installed on the local machine, why are you trying to use @font-face at all?

Comment: It also is strange that you are calling a new `style` element a `headElement`.

Comment: Thanks for all aswers. I am going see this subject CSS Object Model. I really did not know about it.