# Change font according to different languages?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, fonts, angular-translate

I have an application in angularJs and there are three language that i need to support and for every language i need to use different font. I am using angular-translate to change language and it is working fine. I need to change font also when language change, so what i did, i used CSS variable and when languages changes, i change the variable value with font-face name. It was working fine and then i came to know that CSS variable is not working in IE. Then i decided to use another methodology to do this. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355147/font-face-changing-via-javascript) and i thought if i have a font-face like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url('../fonts/roboto-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/roboto-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-display: block;
}
```

I will add new style with same name and different src. But there is a problem that whenever i will change the language i have to add new style with different src. So is there any way to delete font-face in CSS using javascript or is there any way to update or edit the font-face src? Or anyone can tell me another way to do this(when language change, font should also change).

Comment: font is inside some class, so just change classes with the language. Try using `ng-class="{'class-en': lang == 'english', 'class-pk': lang == 'pakistani'}"`, etc.

Comment: I already think about it but i have lots of css classes in which designer specifically mention the font-family.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the following code in a controller:

```
app.controller("bodyController", ($scope) => {
    $scope.lang_fonts = {};
    $scope.lang_fonts["en"] = "font-name";
    $scope.lang_fonts["sp"] = "font-name-2";
    $scope.current_lang = "en";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.fontFamily = $scope.lang_fonts[$scope.current_lang];
    //$("body").css("font-family", $scope.lang_fonts[$scope.current_lang]); // using jQuery
})
```